# Writing y value of Curtate Trochoid in the function of x?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, cycloid

The parametric equations of a trochoid are

$x = Rt-d\sin(t)$

$y = R-d\cos(t)$

For $d < R$, there should be only one corresponding y value for every $x$ value.

So can we express this equation as a form of y(x)?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trochoid.html

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! $y(x)$ would be hard but $x(y)$ is simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to write $y=y(x)$ since this requires to solve the equation$$\sin t=at+b$$analytically for constants $a,b$ which is solvable only numerically.

Comment: So there is no way to know the value of y when one knows x and R and d?

Comment: Unfortunately not in general except in some cases for example if $x=0$ then the only value of $t$ is $0$ and then $y=R-d$.